# File type unknown (application/octet-stream) is not supported, Sendgrid node js file unable to read

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, sendgrid, node-pdfkit

hi guys thank you for your time i have this issues where i generate pdf file using pdfkit and send them using sendgrid in node js, the email was successfully send but the file seems to be corrupt when i tried to open the file in email how ever if i open the file that i save locally work normally (pdf formatted as it intended to),

here let me show my code :

```
    await dbTransaction
        .create(result)
        .then(async (data) => {
            const doc = new PDFdocument({
                size: 'A4',
                margin: {
                    right: 25,
                    left: 25,
                },

            });

            const table = new PDFtable(doc, {
                bottomMargin: 5,
            });

            if (result.is_round_trip === false) {
                const dateNow = moment().format('DD MMMM YYYY');


                table
                    .addPlugin(new (VoilabTable)({
                        column: 'Item',
                    }))
                    .addColumns([
                        {
                            id: 'Item',
                            // header: 'Name',
                            Align: 'left',
                            width: 250,
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'Separator',
                            // header: 'Name',
                            Align: 'center',
                            width: 10,
                        },

                        {
                            id: 'Description',
                            // header: 'Description',
                            align: 'left',
                            width: 250,
                        },

                    ]);


                doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/../../../polis_generate_temp/${result.customer_name.pdf`));
                doc.moveUp(5);
                doc.image('sompo_hd.png', {
                    fit: [150, 100],
                    align: 'left',
                })
                    .moveDown(2.5);


                doc.end();
                transData = data;
            }
```

above i generate my pdf file

and here's the code to send my email

```
            sgMail.setApiKey(example_key);


            const pdfFolder = fs.readdirSync(`${__dirname}/../../../polis`);
            const msg = {
                to: 'example@gmail.com',
                from: 'example@mail.id',
                subject: 'example subject',
                text: 'dev',
                attachments: [],
            };
            const attachMail = {
                content: `${__dirname}/../../../polis/file.pdf`,
                filename: `file.pdf`,
                type: 'application/pdf',
                disposition: 'attachment',
            };
            msg.attachments.push(attachMail);

            await sgMail.send(msg)
                .then(() => {
                    setContent(200, transData);
                    return res.status(200).json(getContentSuccess());
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    setContent(500, errorCode.General.SYSTEM_ERROR);
                    return res.status(500).json(getContentFail(req, err));
                });
```

as you can see i put the sendgript scipt after the dbTransaction promise then, already tried to set it one level just like the transaction and using async-await but it doesnt work, i suspect the pdf kit were not finished to write the file and the sendgrid sent them anyway.

thank you for your time any suggestion and input from yours where very valueable to me.
thanks